# Parsing Environment Canada Website

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-2.6

I am trying to scrape the weather forecast from "https://weather.gc.ca/city/pages/ab-52_metric_e.html". With the code below I am able to get the table containing the data but I'm stuck. During the day the second row contains Today's forecast and the third row contains tonight's forecast. At the end of the day the second row becomes Tonight's forecast and Today's forecast is dropped. What I want to do is parse through the table to get the forecast for Today, Tonight, and each continuing day even if Today's forecast is missing; something like this:

Today: A mix of sun and cloud. 60 percent chance of showers this afternoon with risk of a thunderstorm. Widespread smoke. High 26. UV index 6 or high.
Tonight: Partly cloudy. Becoming clear this evening. Increasing cloudiness before morning. Widespread smoke. Low 13.
Friday: Mainly cloudy. Widespread smoke. Wind becoming southwest 30 km/h gusting to 50 in the afternoon. High 24.

```
#using Beautiful Soup 3, Python 2.6
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import urllib

pageFile = urllib.urlopen("https://weather.gc.ca/city/pages/ab-    52_metric_e.html")
pageHtml = pageFile.read()
pageFile.close()

soup = BeautifulSoup("".join(pageHtml))
data = soup.find("div", {"id": "mainContent"})

forecast = data.find('table',{'class':"table mrgn-bttm-md mrgn-tp-md     textforecast hidden-xs"})
```

Comment: You may want to give [weathergc](https://github.com/jschnurr/weathergc) a try; it returns the current conditions, forecast and watches/warnings as a JSON object.  Forecast periods are individual rows in a list that you can iterate over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like iterate over each line in the table and get the value of the rows. An example would be:

```
forecast = data.find('table',{'class':"table mrgn-bttm-md mrgn-tp-md     textforecast hidden-xs"}).find_all("tr")
for tr in forecast[1:]:
    print " ".join(tr.text.split())
```

With this approach you get the contents of each lines (exclusive the first one which is some header.

Comment: Thanks so much @peter for your reply. Would you explain to me please; if I change the last line to "print  tr. text" I get an error but if I use "print  tr.text.split()" I do not, what exactly is split() doing? Also the first two words in each line are joined, how can I split them?

Comment: First of all I am not peter. Anyway without the error message I cannot tell you what the problem is -- there should be none even if you just write `print tr.text`. Split splits a text across the given expression. In the example above it is whitespace (so new lines, tabs and so on). You can read more about it here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split

Comment: Opps, sorry about that @GHajba. When I change the last line as mentioned above I get: "TodayMainly cloudy. Clearing late this afternoon. Widespread smoke. Wind becoming south 30 km/h gusting to 60 this afternoon. High 25. UV index 4 or moderate.
TonightClear. Widespread smoke becoming hazy this evening. Wind south 30 km/h gusting to 60 becoming light overnight. Low 10.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "wx3.py", line 13, in <module>
    print tr.text
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xa0' in position 4: ordinal not in range(128)"

Comment: in this case use `tr.text.encode('utf-8')` The error tells there is an encoding issue (you get a no-standard character in the result). The you can `split` and `join` the result together if you want.